# Add Google Analytics to an Empty Website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How can I add Google Analytic tracking code to an empty website? It doesn't have .php or .html file. Our Cpanel is empty and we just want to know if how many visitors visits the site. Is their a way to track this site? Do I have to add a .html file or something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your Cpanel for existing tracking? You might have a panel that includes visits.

EDIT:

If you have Cpanel access, more than likely you have FTP access, you can add a index.html file via FTP and then add Google Analytics there.

Comment: How can I checked cpanel for existing tracking? Sorry for this question, I am new to this thing.

Comment: I get what you mean @scott, just like in HostGator there is a panel for Google Analytics Integration. We want to use google analytics is it possible to just create an index.php and put the tracking code their?

Comment: anyone could help me??

Comment: Yeah, if you can add a index.php file you can add Google Analytics

Comment: I did it yesterday, but in the google analytics account js tracking info it says "tracking not installed". I check the real time overview, somehow it is tracking my website and i think its working fine despite the "tracking not installed" info. Thanks for you response @scott!

Comment: Yep, the tracking can take up to 24 hours (I believe) to start showing up, so I would trust the real time results if they're working.

Comment: ps: if your problem is solved, please accept the answer that helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the instructions on http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/google-analytics-integration to setup analytics for you.

If that doesn't work, having a blank html page with analytics code is the best options for you. Its also pretty easy so you wont have to do a lot to get it to work.